# Please help me find the direction of the current electromagnetically induced

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I am currently a newbie to electromagnetism so, please apologize if the question seems very obvious.

I am currently struggling to understand Fleming's Right Hand Rule. [These](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/109aV1dmVLdrI41UFVr_Swyt91xQeQAP9?usp=sharing) experiments are Faraday's experiments where the secondary coil is under the influence of the magnet or primary coil (according to which experiment you're looking at). I want to find out the direction of the current induced on the secondary coil using the said rule. However, I am stuck at finding the motion of the coil in the given cases as they are not moving, instead, the magnet is moving or being turned on or off. For your reference again, these are the experiments in question along with their diagrams:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you can’t determine the direction of the induced current. In my opinion, I don’t think using that right hand rule is a good idea, what you need to know is the principles inside it.

Go check the [Lenz's law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law), that’s very important for you to understand what’s happening when you plug a magnet into a coil. In a word, you will always find the direction of the induced magnetic field that induced by the current of the coil contrary to the direction of the net magnetic flux though the coil.

For example, in one of your problem, the N pole of the magnet is plugged in to the coil, the net flux is left, so the direction of the induced magnetic field will be contrary to that, in this case, the direction will be the right, and then you can determine the direction of the current in the coil.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about finding the direction of induced current then there is a better way to do that , remember **EMF(or current) is always induced in such a way that magnetic field created due to induced emf(or current) opposes the change in magnetic flux through the closed circuit**

Answer (score 1):

Fleming's Right-Hand Rule is for when energy of motion (kinetic energy) is converted into electrical energy, say with a dynamo or generator. (His Left-Hand Rule is the opposite, for converting electrical energy into energy of motion, say in an electrical motor.) In the experiments illustrated: 1. When you move a magnet into a coil forming a circuit, it induces a voltage and current in the coil, which creates a magnetic field which opposes the motion. So it creates a north polarity to repel the north of the magnet. When you move the magnet out of the coil, it induces a voltage and current which creates a magnetic field which again opposes the motion, so a south polarity to attract the north pole of the magnet. This opposing of the motion is Lenz's Law and is indicated by a - (minus) in the right side of the simple equation. If there were not a minus, this would create increasing energy out of nothing. So, it has the be a minus, with the induced current opposing the motion and maintaining conservation of energy in the system. When there is no relative movement of the magnet and coil, this is no kinetic energy to be converted into electrical energy. The faster the movement of the magnet the larger the current. 2. When the circuit for the primary coil is switched on and off, the magnetic field is changing and so induces a current in the secondary coil which produces a field which again opposes the change according to Lenz's Law. When the primary is simply just on or off, there is no change in field and so no current is induced in the secondary coil. Say the primary coil has 10 loops and the secondary coil has 5 loops, the induced voltage is stepped-down to half, but for conservation of nery the current is doubled. When looking at a coil, use the Corkscrew Rule to show you which way the current goes to produce a north or south polarity. Hope this helps.